# Is Windows 7 Home Premium OS good enough for gaming system? or Home File Server?

Tags: windows-7

All I've ever used has been Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate (same thing for XP, only Professional). Is Windows 7 Home Premium 'good enough' for a gaming box? I'd like to share some stuff to my home network from this computer also: Files, photos, videos.

I'm looking for 'first-hand' experience, not Microsoft charts that give you the mile-long view of differences between Windows 7 Editions. Will Home Premium be 'good enough' for not?

Comment: what yard stick are you using to determine "good enough"? This would seem to be a rather subjective question.

Comment: So, by 'gaming system' you want to know if I want to play Tetris, Minesweeper, Chess, or Steam with heavy/graphics intense games?.  The latter, of course.  By Home Files server.... well, good enough, would be 'the ability' to share those.  I'm not sure I could be more specific.

Comment: Given that the only differences are those listed in the charts you say you don't want to look at, and everything else is identical, what are you even worried about? Just look at the differences between Home Premium and Professional, and see if there are any features missing which you need...

Comment: @nhinkle Well, it's not that I don't want to look at them (already have), but as I specified, I wanted to hear from people who actually used w7hp as a gaming system or FS server.

Comment: @l0c0b0x I suppose that's reasonable, but again: if you _know_ that it works fine in Windows 7 Pro, and you _know_ that the same feature exists in Windows 7 Home, then it seems redundant to ask if the feature still works. Up to you though.

Comment: Hehehe... I'm just trying to minimize any "AHA!!!" moments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 Home Premium is designed for most household uses. I have a 3 machine network at home, one connected to my TV to watch videos, one in my office to surf the web, and another that I take to LAN parties. All of them are running windows Home Premium and are all a part of the same [Homegroup](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows-7/windows-7-feature-focus-homegroup). It works great and I am able to move files around quickly and easily. All of my games work and I rarely have any problems.

Answer (score 5):

Home Premium can't join a domain, support Remote Desktop as a server (it can certainly connect to another machine via Remote Desktop though, acting as the client), and other enterprise-tiered features. Sharing on the other hand is certainly possible within Home Premium and works out of the box.

From a gaming perspective I would be more concerned about hardware than your OS version since you have already selected Windows as the platform.

Comment: HP can not act as a Remote Desktop server, but it does have the Remote Desktop client.

Comment: @Xantec Edited for clarification...

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it will work just fine for what you need. I use the 64 bit version on a desktop replacement laptop at home for pretty much the same things and I have never had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your hardware but if it's good enough for gaming you can play with Windows 7 Home Premium; you can easily share your home networks folder like music, pictures, movies and more. If you want more information about Windows 7 Home Premium and other Windows 7 editions look at this [article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/compare) and you can see what you will have ıf you plan to get Home Premium.